# Mysql COUNT function not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a database called articles and I just wanna print out the amount of rows in my database. This is my code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('link', 'database', 'password');
if (!$con) { 
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}           
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles");  
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result)
?>
<p>The amount of rows is <?php echo $row ?>.</p>
```

When I test this code, is just gives me 'The amount of rows is .' as output. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: This is my full code now, but it still doens't work:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('url', 'database', 'password');
if (!$con) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}           
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(URL) AS row_count FROM articles"); 
if (!$result ) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($con);
    exit;
}           
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)
?>
<p>The amount of rows is <?= $row['row_count'] ?>.</p>
```

The error: DB Error, could not query the database MySQL Error: No database selected

Comment: You have no semicolon `;` after `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)`

Comment: You should avoid using the [deprected `mysql_*` functions and use PDO or MySQLi instead](http://www.exchangecore.com/blog/update-deprecated-mysql-extension-pdo_mysql/),

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to print the row.

Use `echo $row[0]` instead

Also, as it's printing nothing, I suspect your query is failing, as FALSE will be `echo`ed as nothing in PHP.

Sidenote: `mysql_*` is deprecated, consider using `PDO` instead.

EDIT:

full code below

```
    <?php
$con = new mysqli('url', 'database', 'password', 'db_name');
if (!$con) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$result = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS row_count FROM articles");

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . $con->error;
    exit;
}           

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>
<p>The amount of rows is <?= $row['row_count'] ?>.</p>
```

Comment: I don't actually wanna print a full array, I just wanna print 1 value: the amount of rows. How do I have to do that?

Comment: I just told you how to.. use $row[0]

Comment: That means your query is failing, you might want to add if (!$row) die(mysql_error()); and tell us what the error is.

Comment: I checked my error log, this is what I get:

PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b676/ipg.splasjcom/Admin.php on line 45 
PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b676/ipg.splasjcom/Admin.php on line 46

Comment: change all your functions to use mysqli_* if you want to use mysqli

Comment: Yes, that is a query error.  And you have to include the resource with the mysqli_query.  Look at my code above and you'll see mysqli_query($link, "MYSQL QUERY")

Comment: I checked it another time and everyting is mysqli_*
I still get the same output...

Comment: You should be using mysqli like this: $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

Comment: I pasted my full code in the question, you can take a look over there.

Comment: You're using mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_assoc, i've added the full code above in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but I'm getting exactly the same output with exactly the same error...

Comment: Post your exact code, you're probably missing something

Comment: Look at my code, see how I have a dbname, change that to whatever your database schema name is.

Comment: I did, this is the error: 
DB Error, could not query the database MySQL Error:

Comment: Here is a more detailed error/warning:
20140613T211306: www.splasj.com/Admin.php 
PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user 'splasj'@'10.%' to database 'articles' in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b676/ipg.splasjcom/Admin.php on line 41 
PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b676/ipg.splasjcom/Admin.php on line 45 
PHP Warning:  main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b676/ipg.splasjcom/Admin.php on line 48

Comment: well looks like your database rejected you , check your permissions

Comment: But when my databse rejects me, why am I able to connect to it then?

Answer (score 1):

You are `echo`ing an array (which should give you error). Instead you can set alias for `COUNT`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM articles");
```

And `echo` it like:

```
<p>The amount of rows is <?php echo $row['Total'] ?>.</p>
```

Comment: @user3739400 : Then your query is failing and there can be a lot of reasons for that from the misspelled table name to the failed connection. You should look in your error log for details or display them in the browser along with `mysql_ error()` function.

Comment: this is what I get when I check my error log:
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b676/ipg.splasjcom/Admin.php on line 45 
PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b676/ipg.splasjcom/Admin.php on line 46

Comment: @user3739400 : Are you using `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions together? Cause this is totally wrong.

Comment: @user3739400 : The first argument should be a connection, the second is for query. See the answer

Comment: I can put my whole code below if you want but that's very unclear in a comment discussion...

Comment: @user3739400 : I've already updated a line with `mysqli_query`, just copy it.

Comment: @user3739400 : Every time you want to write something like `It doesn't work` bare in mind that we all are not sitting with you, so we actually can't see how it is not working, so ___specify___ the way it is not working, with error messages from the logs and functions, that I've already mentioned above. P.S. : Have you tried to execute your query in the IDE (like MySQL Workbench)?

Comment: I pasted my full code in the question, you can take a look over there.

Comment: @user3739400 : Can you post all ___error messages___?

Comment: The only error messages I get are the one I posted in my question.

Comment: I tried that, And I'm getting the exact same error.

Comment: Here is a more detailed error/warning:
20140613T211306: www.splasj.com/Admin.php 
PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user 'splasj'@'10.%' to database 'articles' in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b676/ipg.splasjcom/Admin.php on line 41 
PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b676/ipg.splasjcom/Admin.php on line 45 
PHP Warning:  main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b676/ipg.splasjcom/Admin.php on line 48

Answer (score -1):

As others said, you're trying to print the array (hence the `fetch_array`), when you need to print something in the array.

Also, `mysql_*` is depreciated, I use `mysqli_*` which is very similar and easy to switch to.

Also, instead of `*`, try a fieldname in the count.  I usually use the index, or primary key or something.

```
<?php
  $link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno($link)) {
        echo 'Could not select database:' . DB_NAME;
        exit;
  }          

  $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(fieldname) AS row_count FROM articles");  
  if (!$result ) {
            echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
            echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($link);
            exit;
  }

  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)
?>
<p>The amount of rows is <?= $row['row_count'] ?>.</p>
```

Comment: Added code to catch the error if the query is failing.

Comment: 1) Don't just vote down answers if they don't copy/paste work.  2) Try with the code I added to catch a query error.  3) My code requires you to use mysqli_ and requires you to replace some values such as the DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME etc.  I also suggested you use a fieldname, did you use a field/column, or did you just copy what I had verbatim?

Comment: I didn't vote down your code, why would I? And I will try your code, thank you.

Comment: This is what I get from the error log:
DB Error, could not query the database MySQL Error:

Comment: If there is nothing after the MySQL Error:, but you didn't get an error with the connection, then something funky is going on with the query.  Are you mixing mysql_ and mysqli_ ?  You can't sent a mysql_ resource in a mysqli_query for instance.

Comment: No I'm not using them together, I checked and double checked it... 
I really don't know the problem...

Comment: I pasted my full code in the question, you can take a look over there.